# Issue with the numbering in table of content

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering

I have this numbering :

> I. Introduction
>
> I.1.blabla
>
> I.2.blablabla

I would like to have it like this :

> I. Introduction
>
> 1.blabla
>
> 2.blablabla

Comment: What is your documentclass? `book`. It looks like you are using `\chapter` for `Introduction`, with Roman numbers. Try `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}` in the document preamble

Comment: no, i'm using report  but i think you did not understand me well . actually, my problem is in the table of content

Comment: Well, you did  not give much information, did you? At the moment it's unclear, what you mean. Shall the numbering changed in the ToC only?

Comment: yes you're right actually the issue is a bit particular. But in the table of content, i want the numbreing to change in sections and subsections and appear without the roman number of the chapter

Comment: It's late here, I should sleep, but I'll try tomorrow unless others have not provided an answer so far

Comment: okey tahnks anyway and good night :)

Comment: Take a look on my possible solution. I am not sure I have understood you correctly.

Answer (score 2):

This uses a patch to the `\@sect` command, writing explicit arabic numbers to the ToC instead of the `\thesection`. However, this is a quick hack, all `*section` types will just use `\arabic{*section}`. As long this is no issue, the code is ok.

```
\documentclass{report}


\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@sect}{%
  \protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
}{%
  \protect\numberline{\arabic{#1}.}%
}{\typeout{success}}{\typeout{failed}}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction}

\section{First}
\section{Second}
\subsection{First subsection}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can patch `\@sect` so that it doesn't issue a generic `\numberline` command, but rather a specific `\numberline<level>` command, that we can define to gobble up to the first period and do a normal `\numberline` with what remains.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@sect}
  {\protect\numberline}
  {\expandafter\protect\csname numberline#1\endcsname}
  {}{}
\def\remove@to@period#1.#2\@nil{\numberline{#2}}
\newcommand{\numberlinesection}[1]{%
  \remove@to@period#1\@nil
}
\let\numberlinesubsection\numberlinesection
\let\numberlinesubsubsection\numberlinesection
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}\label{ch-intro}

\section{Bla bla}

With a reference to chapter~\ref{ch-intro}
and to section~\ref{sec-bbb}

\section{Bla bla bla}\label{sec-bbb}

\end{document}
```

[image]